# Error in return value type in function in C

Tags: c, return-type

I need to implement the `strcpy` source in C.

I dont understand why am i have this eror in line 15 (in the line- "return saved;"):

> Error: return value type does not match function type

*this is the full source:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


char str_cpy(char *d, const char *s)
{
    char *saved = d;
    while (*s)
    {
        *d++ = *s++;
    }
    *d = 0;
    return saved; // line 15. here the eror
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

}
```

Comment: change the `return` type from `char` to `char *`

Comment: The type of `saved` is `char *`, while the return type is `char`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `saved` which is of type `char *`, so declare you're function returning `char *` as,

`char * str_cpy(char *d, const char *s)`

Answer (score 2):

You declared your function to return `char` and you return `char*`.

Change the function signature to return `char*`.

```
char* str_cpy(char *d, const char *s)
```